# Reading App.config works fine but saving it crashes the application

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I've built an application with App.config file included and created the Windows Installer for it via Setup Wizard project. When I run the installed application, it can read the configurations flawlessly, but when I make changes and save the configurations, the application just crash.

Here is my code:

```cs
Configuration applicationConfiguration = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Reading works just fine.
LogFilePath = applicationConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["LogFilePath"].Value;

LogFilePath = "some string here";

applicationConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["LogFilePath"].Value = LogFilePath;

// But saving it crashes the application. Only the .Save() line that making it crashed.
applicationConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Define "crashing". Are you seeing an exception? If so, what is the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to docummentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx possibly user that runs your map has read permission, but does not have write permission (to file and to directory)

> To get the Configuration object for a resource,
>   your code must have read permissions on all the configuration files
>   from which it inherits settings. To update a configuration file, your
>   code must additionally have write permissions for both the
>   configuration file and the directory in which it exists.

Comment: Oh man, actually I've guessed it as one of possibilities. And yes, you are right, as I just saw the exception coming from a message box that I created just for showing it: `An error occured loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'temporary file path' is denied. (Full path of configuration file)`

Comment: The easiest solutions are the last that comes into mind. i just spend 2 hours searching why form data did'n bind to model and finally saw that i forgot to define setter methods, so i know how it feels.